# Using sed to clean up SchemaSync output

Tags: sed

I have created a small sample of what I'm working with at this point. I am trying to properly quote the DEFAULT values, specifically #2 `DEFAULT ONE` value should be quoted as `DEFAULT 'ONE'`:

```
#1 CREATE TABLE `table` (`column` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
#2 ALTER TABLE `table` MODIFY COLUMN `column2` enum('ONE','TWO') NOT NULL DEFAULT ONE AFTER `column1`;
#3 ALTER TABLE `table` MODIFY COLUMN `column` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' FIRST;
```

I am currently using the following line against the above lines in order to fix line #2:

```
sed "s/DEFAULT \([a-zA-Z0-9_.]*\)/DEFAULT '\1'/g"
```

This is the output I'm getting:

```
#1 CREATE TABLE `table` (`column` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 'NULL') ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT 'CHARSET'=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
#2 ALTER TABLE `table` MODIFY COLUMN `column2` enum('ONE','TWO') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ONE' AFTER `column1`;
#3 ALTER TABLE `table` MODIFY COLUMN `column` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '''' FIRST;
```

As you can see it fixes line #2 but #1 & #3 now have issues.

```
#1 DEFAULT 'NULL'    (should remain DEFAULT NULL)
#1 DEFAULT 'CHARSET' (should remain DEFAULT CHARSET)
#2 DEFAULT 'ONE'     (GOOD!)
#3 DEFAULT ''''      (should remain DEFAULT '')
```

Is there a way to adjust the sed to ignore specific patterns such as `DEFAULT NULL` or `DEFAULT CHARSET` or `DEFAULT ''`?

```
sed "s/DEFAULT (not followed by NULL|CHARSET|'')\([a-zA-Z0-9_.]*\)/DEFAULT '\1'/g"
```

Or perhaps there is a better approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
sed -E "s/DEFAULT (NULL|CHARSET)/DEFAULT_\1/g; s/DEFAULT ([[:alnum:]_.]+)/DEFAULT '\1'/g; s/DEFAULT_(NULL|CHARSET)/DEFAULT \1/g" file
```

This works in three steps:

1. `s/DEFAULT (NULL|CHARSET)/DEFAULT_\1/g`

   This hides the DEFAULT values that you don't want to change.
2. `s/DEFAULT ([[:alnum:]_.]+)/DEFAULT '\1'/g`

   This changes the values that you do want to change.

   Note that I changed the `*` to `+`.  This means that empty strings will not be matched.  This solves the problem in line #3.

   I also changed `[a-zA-Z0-9]` to `[:alnum:]` so that the regex would match all alphanumeric characters in a unicode-safe way.  (If this isn't what you wanted, just change this part back.)
3. `s/DEFAULT_(NULL|CHARSET)/DEFAULT \1/g`

   This changes back the ones that you don't want to change.

This approach assumes that neither `DEFAULT_NULL` nor `DEFAULT_CHARSET` appear in your actual input.  Based on what you have shown so far, this looks like a safe assumption.

#### Example

With your input file:

```
$ cat file
#1 CREATE TABLE `table` (`column` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
#2 ALTER TABLE `table` MODIFY COLUMN `column2` enum('ONE','TWO') NOT NULL DEFAULT ONE AFTER `column1`;
#3 ALTER TABLE `table` MODIFY COLUMN `column` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' FIRST;
```

Our command produces:

```
$ sed -E "s/DEFAULT (NULL|CHARSET)/\n\1/g; s/DEFAULT ([[:alnum:]_.]+)/DEFAULT '\1'/g; s/\n(NULL|CHARSET)/DEFAULT \1/g" file
#1 CREATE TABLE `table` (`column` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
#2 ALTER TABLE `table` MODIFY COLUMN `column2` enum('ONE','TWO') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ONE' AFTER `column1`;
#3 ALTER TABLE `table` MODIFY COLUMN `column` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' FIRST;
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Love the explanation breakdown. Thank you very much! Very helpful.

Comment: What if `DEFAULT_FOO` already exists as a string in the input? If you use `\n` instead of `_` to create the temp string then you KNOW that doesn't already exist in `\n`-separated input like sed reads by default.

Answer (score 2):

If `Perl` is your option, please try:

```
perl -pe "s/(DEFAULT) (?!(NULL|CHARSET|''))([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/\1 '\3'/g" file
```

Output:

```
#1 CREATE TABLE `table` (`column` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
#2 ALTER TABLE `table` MODIFY COLUMN `column2` enum('ONE','TWO') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ONE' AFTER `column1`;
#3 ALTER TABLE `table` MODIFY COLUMN `column` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' FIRST;
```

Comment: This also works perfectly although @John1024's answer uses sed. I really do like this though. It seems very clean and easily manageable.. I'm pretty sure I'll be adding more words to the list in the near future as well (e.g. CURRENT_TIMESTAMP). So thank you very much for sharing this answer!

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
awk -v RS='DEFAULT \\w+' -v ORS= '
    RT { split(RT,rt); if (rt[2] !~ /^(NULL|CHARSET)$/) RT=rt[1]" \047"rt[2]"\047" }
    { print $0 RT }
' file
#1 CREATE TABLE `table` (`column` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
#2 ALTER TABLE `table` MODIFY COLUMN `column2` enum('ONE','TWO') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ONE' AFTER `column1`;
#3 ALTER TABLE `table` MODIFY COLUMN `column` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' FIRST;
```